# Intercept save from external application in C#

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, save

Currently I do this:

1. Initialize and start a [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. Detect a save action (after it has been written to the HDD/media)
3. Open a filestream from the saved file (after making sure that the external application has closed it)
4. Encrypt the file using an encryption method in the program
5. Save the encrypted file
6. Delete the original using File.Delete

What's wrong with that is File.Delete doesn't erase the file from memory, but only marks the memory as able to be written over.

What I want to do:

1. Start (insert whatever object is necessary here)
2. Detect a save event *before* it is written to the HDD/media
3. "Import" (perhaps the wrong word?) the data into my C# program (preferably through a stream)
4. Encrypt
5. Save

This way there is no unencrypted version hanging around after the process is finished.

My question is this: How (if possible) can I detect a save action before it is actually written to the media, and then intercept that save? (I don't know how to do steps 2 or 3 in the "What I want to do" section)

Alternatively, I'd accept knowing how to securely delete the file from C# (without wiping the entire disk) (so I can use what I currently do but instead of File.Delete, actually erase the file from the media), but I think that this is going to be harder.

For reference, this is the basic structure I use now. It's obviously not what I want to do:

```
private void OnFileSave(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("File saved");
    Console.WriteLine("Encrypting File");

    try
    {
        using (FileStream s = File.Open(e.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
        {
            SecureString pw = GetPassword();
            using (SecureStringWrapper wrapper = new SecureStringWrapper(pw))
            {
                EncryptorProgram.EncryptFile(e.FullPath, wrapper.ToBtyeArray(), saltBytes); 
                //Writing of the new file and file deletion take place in the encrypt method
                Console.WriteLine("File encrypted");
            }
        }
    }
    //The file is still open in the other program - do not encrypt!
    catch (IOException ex) { Console.WriteLine("File still open"); }
}
```

Note: I need this to detect a save from any program if possible. I've been using notepad to test, but I would like to detect anytime a file is (going to be) saved to the disk (in some specific TBD directory) from any program (Word, Excel, non-Microsoft programs, etc).

Comment: Just enable BitLocker and be done with it. What you want shouldn't be done with C# and maybe not even with code that runs in user mode, write a kernel driver that intercepts File IO. And keep in mind that the program that just wrote that file *also* has the unencrypted version of that content in memory. You can't make something secure as an after thought.

Comment: you can intercept actual file IO calls in user mode with something like: https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokany (there's a .NET wrapper for dokany here: https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokan-dotnet)